# Countdown timer stops ticking when the phone screen is locked

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I wrote a code - a timer that measures the number of seconds entered. While the timer counts down the seconds when I lock the phone screen, after unlocking the screen after a long time, the timer stopped a few seconds after locking the screen. Is there any way to fix this?

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  var workSeconds = parseInt(document.getElementById('work-seconds').value);
  var workSecondsCount = workSeconds;
  var worktimer = setInterval(workSecCount,1000);
  function workSecCount(){
    workSecondsCount--;
    workSecondsCount < 10 ? document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "0" + workSecondsCount : document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = workSecondsCount;
    if(workSecondsCount == 0){
      document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "DONE";
      workSecondsCount = workSeconds;
      clearInterval(worktimer);
    }
  };
});
```

```
<input type="number" id="work-seconds" placeholder="seconds" min="0">
<button id="btn">START</button>
<p>Work Timer : <span id="workSecs"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `workSecondsCount` you need to rely on current time, then you can compensate time gaps.

```js
var worktimer = 0;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  if (!worktimer) clearInterval(worktimer);
  var workSeconds = parseInt(document.getElementById('work-seconds').value);
  var workSecondsCount = new Date().getTime() + workSeconds * 1000;
  function workSecCount(){
    const secondsCount = Math.ceil((workSecondsCount  - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
    secondsCount < 10 ? document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "0" + secondsCount : document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = secondsCount;
    if(secondsCount <= 0){
      document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "DONE";
      if (worktimer) {
        clearInterval(worktimer);
        worktimer = 0;
      }
    }
  };
  workSecCount();
  worktimer = setInterval(workSecCount,1000);
});
```

Comment: Wow! I thank you soo much! But why does the countdown start, for example, when I enter 20s, it starts with 18s?

Comment: it's because of the setInterval, it executes the function after 1000ms, you need to call the function right after the declaration. I'll update the answer. Also I've changed `floor` to `Math.ceil`, now it should be better.

Comment: Sometimes, although very rarely, if I click the start button to start the countdown, the seconds count down every 2 instead of 1. Do you know what this can do?

Comment: move worktimer out of the listener and clear it first on every click be sure there there's no second interval running.

Comment: Could he explain more? You mean to delete eventListener click on btn?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The idea is that worktimer is global and control interval of all clicks on the element.

Comment: You've helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: I have a question. I've expanded the code and I have a problem with it again, could you please help me? Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500333/timer-with-animated-wheels-and-errors-with-the-screen-locked

Comment: sure, I'll take a look tonight.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: checking currently, I'll prepare feedback soon.

Comment: I'm very excited! ;))